# Spark: Could not load native gpl library

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I had the following error when trying to run a very simple spark job (which uses logistic regression with SGD in mllib):

```
ERROR GPLNativeCodeLoader: Could not load native gpl library
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no gplcompression in java.library.path
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1738)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1028)
    at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.GPLNativeCodeLoader.<clinit>(GPLNativeCodeLoader.java:32)
    at com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec.<clinit>(LzoCodec.java:71)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.getCodecClasses(CompressionCodecFactory.java:128)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodecFactory.<init>(CompressionCodecFactory.java:175)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat.configure(TextInputFormat.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setJobConf(ReflectionUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:75)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:133)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getInputFormat(HadoopRDD.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:181)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:93)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.FilteredRDD.compute(FilteredRDD.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MappedRDD.compute(MappedRDD.scala:31)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.FilteredRDD.compute(FilteredRDD.scala:34)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:262)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:51)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:187)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
14/08/06 20:32:11 ERROR LzoCodec: Cannot load native-lzo without native-hadoop
```

This is the command I used to submit the job:

```
~/spark/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/bin/spark-submit \
--class com.jk.sparktest.Test \
--master yarn-cluster \
--num-executors 40 \
~/sparktest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

The actual java command is :

```
/usr/java/latest/bin/java -cp /apache/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/hadoop-common-2.2.0.2.0.6.0-61.jar:/apache/hadoop/lib/hadoop-lzo-0.6.0.jar::/home/jilei/spark/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/conf:/home/jilei/spark/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/lib/spark-assembly-1.0.0-hadoop2.2.0.jar:/home/jilei/spark/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.1.jar:/home/jilei/spark/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.2.jar:/home/jilei/spark/spark-1.0.0-bin-hadoop2/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.1.jar:/apache/hadoop/conf:/apache/hadoop/conf  \
-XX:MaxPermSize=128m \
-Djava.library.path= 
-Xms512m -Xmx512m org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit \
--class com.jk.sparktest.Test  \
--master yarn-cluster  \
--num-executors 40   \
~/sparktest-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Seems the `-Djava.library.path` is not set. I also tried the java command above and supplied the native lib directory to the `java.library.path`, but still got the same errors. This is the content of the native lib directory:

```
ls /apache/hadoop/lib/native/
libgplcompression.a   libgplcompression.so    libgplcompression.so.0.0.0  libhadooppipes.a 
libhadoop.so.1.0.0  libhdfs.a   libhdfs.so.0.0.0  libsnappy.so.1
libgplcompression.la  libgplcompression.so.0  libhadoop.a                 libhadoop.so         
libhadooputils.a    libhdfs.so  libsnappy.so      libsnappy.so.1.1.4
```

Any idea on what's wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I tried a java mapreduce job, it can successfully load the the gpl library.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why what you tried with `java.library.path` didn't work.  I solved a problem similar to what you described by adding the argument:

```
--driver-library-path /usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native/
```

where `/usr/lib/hadoop-lzo/lib/native/` contained `libgplcompression.so`.